# VirtualBox stuck in Full Screen mode

Tags: fullscreen, virtualbox

I looked all over and wasn't able to find a clean answer for this.

The problem is:  when you're stuck in full screen mode in VirtualBox and have no way of triggering the host key to exit out (in my case:  Citrixing in on OS X to a Windows machine running an Ubuntu Virtual Box VM... yeah, i know...)

So, I was able to piece together a couple of comments on the web for the following solution...

[This doesn't work because you shouldn't edit the u.vbox file directly](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=14648)

[This gives a general way to set configuration on the command line](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1689)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to exit VirtualBox.

Second, you'll want to set fullscreen to off:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" setextradata u GUI/Fullscreen off
```

Launch VirtualBox and start your VM.

Finally, go back to doing whatever your real job was to begin with...